# crossbar router start without docker

Tags: autobahn, crossbar

Installed `crossbar.io` using `pip install crossbar` in Windows 10 and `python 3.7`.

From cmd, run the following commands:

```
crossbar init
crossbar start
```

But the router does not start. The error logs are as follows ([full logs here](https://pastebin.com/VtTvKcky)):

```
2020-09-09T22:13:48+0530 [Router      67564] Router transport created for "transport002" [transport_class=<crossbar.worker.transport.RouterWebTransport>]
2020-09-09T22:13:48+0530 [Router      67564] Created "static" Web service on root path "/" of Web transport "transport002"
2020-09-09T22:13:48+0530 [Router      67564] Cannot listen on transport endpoint: [Failure instance: Traceback: <class 'twisted.internet.error.CannotListenError'>: Couldn't listen on any:8080: [WinError 10048] Only one usage of each socket address (protocol/network address/port) is normally permitted.
autobahn-python\examplestest\cbio\lib\site-packages\twisted\internet\defer.py:1418:_inlineCallbacks
autobahn-python\examplestest\cbio\lib\site-packages\crossbar\worker\transport.py:234:start
autobahn-python\examplestest\cbio\lib\site-packages\crossbar\common\twisted\endpoint.py:584:create_listening_port_from_config
autobahn-python\examplestest\cbio\lib\site-packages\twisted\internet\endpoints.py:495:listen
--- <exception caught here> ---
autobahn-python\examplestest\cbio\lib\site-packages\crossbar\worker\transport.py:234:start
autobahn-python\examplestest\cbio\lib\site-packages\twisted\internet\defer.py:122:execute
autobahn-python\examplestest\cbio\lib\site-packages\twisted\internet\iocpreactor\reactor.py:157:listenTCP
autobahn-python\examplestest\cbio\lib\site-packages\twisted\internet\iocpreactor\tcp.py:458:startListening
]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "autobahn-python\examplestest\cbio\lib\site-packages\twisted\internet\defer.py", line 1418, in _inlineCallbacks
    result = g.send(result)
  File "autobahn-python\examplestest\cbio\lib\site-packages\crossbar\worker\transport.py", line 234, in start
    self.log,
  File "autobahn-python\examplestest\cbio\lib\site-packages\crossbar\common\twisted\endpoint.py", line 584, in create_listening_port_from_config
    return endpoint.listen(factory)
  File "autobahn-python\examplestest\cbio\lib\site-packages\twisted\internet\endpoints.py", line 495, in listen
    interface=self._interface)
--- <exception caught here> ---
  File "autobahn-python\examplestest\cbio\lib\site-packages\crossbar\worker\transport.py", line 234, in start
    self.log,
  File "autobahn-python\examplestest\cbio\lib\site-packages\twisted\internet\defer.py", line 122, in execute
    result = callable(*args, **kw)
  File "autobahn-python\examplestest\cbio\lib\site-packages\twisted\internet\iocpreactor\reactor.py", line 157, in listenTCP
    p.startListening()
  File "autobahn-python\examplestest\cbio\lib\site-packages\twisted\internet\iocpreactor\tcp.py", line 458, in startListening
    raise error.CannotListenError(self.interface, self.port, le)
twisted.internet.error.CannotListenError: Couldn't listen on any:8080: [WinError 10048] Only one usage of each socket address (protocol/network address/port) is normally permitted.

2020-09-09T22:13:48+0530 [Controller  65984] Could not start node: Traceback (most recent call last):
--- <exception caught here> ---
  File "autobahn-python\examplestest\cbio\lib\site-packages\crossbar\node\node.py", line 468, in start
    res = yield self.personality.Node.boot(self)
  File "autobahn-python\examplestest\cbio\lib\site-packages\crossbar\node\node.py", line 608, in boot_from_config
    yield d
  File "autobahn-python\examplestest\cbio\lib\site-packages\crossbar\node\node.py", line 581, in configure_worker
    yield config_fn(worker_logname, worker_id, worker)
  File "autobahn-python\examplestest\cbio\lib\site-packages\crossbar\node\node.py", line 731, in _configure_native_worker_router
    options=CallOptions())
autobahn.wamp.exception.ApplicationError: ApplicationError(error=<crossbar.error.cannot_listen>, args=['Cannot listen on transport endpoint: {log_failure}'], kwargs={}, enc_algo=None, callee=None, callee_authid=None, callee_authrole=None, forward_for=None)

2020-09-09T22:13:48+0530 [Controller  65984] sending TERM to subprocess 67564
2020-09-09T22:13:48+0530 [Controller  65984] waiting for 67564 to exit...
2020-09-09T22:13:48+0530 [Controller  65984] Native worker connection closed uncleanly: A process has ended with a probable error condition: process ended with exit code 1.
2020-09-09T22:13:48+0530 [Controller  65984] detached session 1935629316883057 from realm "crossbar" (authid="crossbar.process.67564", authrole="crossbar.worker.worker001", detached 1 sessions total) <crossbar.router.router.Router.detach>
2020-09-09T22:13:48+0530 [Controller  65984] Node worker worker001 ended with error ([Failure instance: Traceback (failure with no frames): <class 'twisted.internet.error.ProcessTerminated'>: A process has ended with a probable error condition: process ended with exit code 1.
])
2020-09-09T22:13:48+0530 [Controller  65984] Checking for node shutdown: worker_exit_success=False, shutdown_requested=False, node_shutdown_triggers=['shutdown_on_worker_exit']
2020-09-09T22:13:48+0530 [Controller  65984] Node worker ended, and trigger 'shutdown_on_worker_exit' is active: will shutdown node ..
2020-09-09T22:13:48+0530 [Controller  65984] Node shutdown requested (restart=False, mode=None, reactor.running=True) ..
```

Note: What I'm actually want to achieve is posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63544993/python-websocket-server-client-pubsub). I found `crossbar` and `autobahn` might be useful. To use them for my context, a router is required.

What I missed? How to start a router without the docker?

Comment: ```twisted.internet.error.CannotListenError: Couldn't listen on any:8080: [WinError 10048] Only one usage of each socket address (protocol/network address/port) is normally permitted.
``` Looks like your port 8080 is already in use. I would restart your terminal or your computer and try again.

Comment: Yup, done, changing the port number resolves it. Thanks.